# UDP Packet Loss From Android (GoogleGlass) to Arduino over Wi-Fi

Tags: android, arduino, udp, wifi, google-glass

I'm busy improving my undergraduate thesis, *Gimbal Control by Means of Google Glass.* I have managed to send UDP packets from Google Glass to an Arduino with a Wi-Fi shield attached.

Both the Arduino's Wi-Fi shield and Google Glass is connected to my Android tablet's wireless hotspot (therefore creating a wireless link between Glass and the Arduino), the reason being that the Arduino Wi-Fi shield does not have the hardware capability to act as an Access Point.

My problem is that many, many UDP packets are getting lost and never arriving at the Arduino, from Glass. I have set up a counter on Arduino counting how many packets are received, and assigned an ID to each packet being sent from Glass. At packet transmission rate of 10Hz, after a minute almost 100 packets seems to dissappear.

Is there a assignable cause to this problem? Does it have to do with the Android tablet hotspot? Any input or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try using TCP for this? It's ok for UDP to lose packets.